# Variable with weird value in gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86, nasm

I'm kind of a 'noob' but I don't understand why "print WeirdValue" return me "16777216" (1000000000000000000000000) with this code:

```
section .data

    Var db 0

    WeirdValue db 0
```

when in

```
section .data

    Var  dd 0

    WeirdValue db 0
```

It return right '0'.

I'm on a 64bit system, and I'm using the command

```
nasm -f elf32
```

for assembling the code.

Does someone have a clue ?

Comment: I don't know much assembly, but it looks like it's because you're redeclaring a variable with the same name as another one within the same scope, and that's causing some kind of error or data corruption.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm not redeclaring the same variable; it's two different codes ;-).

Comment: Where is the code for returning a value?

Comment: I was checking the value in gdb, with the command "print WeirdValue".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"db" declares a byte. 16777216 does not fit in a byte, so your printing function is printing a dword (can be declared with "dd", which you used in the second example). It is printing the correct value (i.e. the low-order byte is 0), and the reason it is printing an odd number is because at the address [WeirdValue + 3] there is a byte which was containing 0x01 at the time.

Edit - I noticed you're using "db" both times - My guess is that the latter code brings the WeirdValue closer to the boundary of an 8-byte aligned value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, the declaration of 'WeirdValue' is the same; it's only the declaration of another variable above this one that creates this. Do you have an idea of how could I 'align' the whole thing correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
As pointed by Score_Under, "print WeirdValue" printed the variable as a double word, while it was a byte; not sure why.
I simply inspect the value of the variable with "x /b &WeirdValue" (/b = byte).

Thanks for your help ;-).